# Sequence of unitary operators is unitary

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

> If $T_n$ is a sequence of unitary linearbounded operators and $T_n\to T$ in the norm of $B(H,H)$ where $H$ is a Hilbert Space ,is it true that $T$ is linear bounded and unitary.

Steps:

- I have shown that $T$ is bounded.
- In order for $T$ to be unitary $T$ must be bijective.But I am unable to show that sequence of bijective linear bounded operators is bijective.

Please help.If the second criterion is fulfilled is the result true in general.

Any hints will be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to prove that the unitary operators are closed. An operator $U$ is unitary if and only if $U^{\dagger} U = U U^{\dagger} = I$, and these are closed conditions, so the conclusion is immediate.

It is *not* true that a convergent sequence of invertible operators converges to an invertible operator; you can already write down a counterexample in the finite-dimensional case, where $GL_n$ is dense in $M_n$. Invertibility is an open rather than a closed condition.

Comment: Thank you but what is meant by "they are closed conditions".Is it possible to elaborate  a bit

Comment: @Ben: a closed condition on a point in a space $X$ is a condition such that the set of all points satisfying it is closed. A natural source of closed conditions is conditions of the form "$f(x) = y$," where $f : X \to Y$ is a continuous function and $y \in Y$ is a point, which is the case here.

Answer (score 4):

It is well known that $B(H)$, the space of bounded operators on a Hilbert space $H$, with the natural operator composition, the operator-norm and the adjoint operation is a $C^*$-algebra. In particular, the operations are continuous with respect to the norm. This means that if $T_n\to T$ then $T_n^{*}\to T^*$ and also
$T^{*}_nT_n\to T^{*}T$. If $T_n$ is unitary for each $n$, then $T_n^{*}T_n=Id$ for each $n$, and so $T^*T=Id$ by continuity. Similarly, $TT^*=Id$. In particular, if $y\in H$, then $T(T^*y)=y$, so $T$ is surjective, and it is also injective, because it is an isometriy: $||Tx||=||x||$ for all $x$.

Comment: There's no need to go all the way up to the C*-algebra axioms (in particular, there's no need to appeal to the C*-identity). We just need to know that taking adjoints and taking compositions are both norm-continuous.

Comment: I disagree. Structures and their names are designed in order that we think in terms of them, and not start every time from scratch.

Comment: That's fine, but you're using the wrong level of structure. In fact the conclusion holds under the weaker hypothesis that we're working in a Banach *-algebra (with isometric involution).

Comment: I disagree again. Let's agree on this: when solving problems in mathematics, you'll choose your level of structure, and I'll choose mine.

Comment: Aren't you persistent. I never claimed that isometries are surjective. Read again.

Comment: Ah, I misread it. My apologies.