# Collection of all unitary operators in a Hilbert space is a closed set

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, inner-products

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space. $\mathcal{U(H)}$ be the set of all unitary operators on H. Then I want to show that $\mathcal{U(H)}$ is a (norm-) closed subset of the Banach space $\mathcal{L(H)}$, the space of all bounded Linear operators on H.

I have tried taking a sequence of unitary operators on $\mathcal{U(H)}$, but I couldn't conclude. Can somebody please guide me?

Comment: check https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2185937/sequence-of-unitary-operators-is-unitary?rq=1

Comment: @DanielSchepler I have edited the part of $\mathcal{L(H)}$ . The operator you have mentioned is just an isomtery right? Is it a unitary operator? I am referring to Functional Analysis - spectral theory by V S Sunder. I have very limited Knowledge, so excuse any mistakes.

Comment: Oh, right, I forgot a unitary operator also needs to be surjective.

Comment: I think the maps $U \mapsto U^* U$ and $U \mapsto U U^*$ should both be continuous functions $\mathcal{L}(H) \to \mathcal{L}(H)$.

Comment: The definition mostly used is U*U=UU*= Identity operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $L(H)$ is complete, a Cauchy sequence $\{U_n\}$ of unitaries converges to some operator $T$. We also have
$$
\|U_n^*-T^*\|=\|(U_n-t)^*\|=\|U_n-T\|\to0. 
$$
That is $U_n^*\to T^*$. Now
\begin{align}
\|I-T^*T\|
&=\|U_n^*U_n-T^*T\|\\[0.3cm]
&\leq \|U_n^*U_n-U_n^*T\|+\|U_n^*T-T^*T\|\\[0.3cm]
&\leq\|U_n^*\|\,\|U_n-T\|+\|U_n^*-T^*\|\,\|T\|\\[0.3cm]
&=\|U_n-T\|+\|U_n-T\|\,\|T\|\\[0.3cm]
&\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0.
\end{align}
So $T^*T=I$. An entirely similar estimate shows that $TT^*=I$, and hence $T$ is a unitary.